# What came first, the Universe or the Physical laws that govern the Universe?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, laws-of-physics

This sounds like the Egg and the Hen question but I am curious about this. If universe came first and created physical laws for itself, then what created the law or the principle as a consequence of which the universe came into existence in the first place?  And if there where pre-existing physical laws that governed the big bang or whatever the origin of the universe was, then where did those laws come from and what were they a part of? If we assume that creation and destruction of universe is cyclic and the same laws are carried onto the next creation and destruction cycle then shouldn't the law which is governing this cycle be a consequence or a part of some bigger something (like a mega-verse). Whichever the case, we again come down to same basic question as in the title.

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps this chapter of [String theory - Criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory#Criticism) contains interesting things to reword your question

Comment: @igael wasn't really useful but thanks, anyway.

Comment: What's with the downvote? Just because our knowledge isn't (and perhaps will never be) sufficient to answer, doesn't make it metaphysics, or a bad question; just a question that can be answered with "We don't know" (which fortunately the anwers provided so far do).

Comment: Impossible to answer your question is. Meditate on this many have.

Comment: I'd say it is metaphysics, because the answer can depend on one's philosophy of physics. E.g. if one believes that physical laws are invented and not discovered, physical laws clearly come after the beginning of the universe.

Comment: It depends on your definition of 'the Universe'

Comment: @fqq: I have no clou of physics. But saying it depends on MY philosophy of physics is wrong. It may be related to my philosphy, what I see as right or wrong. But there is just one valid law (and even if not, thats not dependent on anyone definition of it; And even if this... YOU can't know.) and about that we dont know yet.

Comment: Well, in a reductionist universe, physical laws and the universe are the same thing. In some laws, it's rather obvious (general relativity describes gravity as fundamentally arising from the topology of the universe), while others are a bit harder to see. And science rests pretty much entirely on reductionism - an assumption that's working quite well so far. Of course, this is within a context where "Universe" means "everything" - if we find that our "microuniverse" is really just a part of something bigger, and different, it might be that the fundmental "laws" are no longer really fundamental

Comment: "*If universe came first and created physical laws for itself*" - I have grave doubts that this expresses anything meaningful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the nature of the existence of physical laws is philosophy of physics (meta-physics in the literal sense).

Comment: Also, "first" or "last" doesn't make any sense in this context, because *time is part of the spacetime structure of the universe, not extrinsic to it*.

Answer (score 8):

I believe a great answer to your question is:

**We don't know**

We still can't resolve the time before electroweak interactions, so how can we even come close to answering this question?

You might get answers from some theories (or I prefer to call them theorems because they're only math until today) like string theory or loop quantum gravity or M-theory or whatever... but we're not even able to test any of these! So my recommendation is: If someone claims they're giving you an answer with certainty, you have to know they're lying (which is why I'm starting to dislike guys like Michio Kaku, who keeps giving certainties about string theory as facts, probably to get funding). Answers given here are only bound to the mathematical formulation of the theory related to it, which is still not testable.

One more important point you have to be careful about with such questions is *drawing conclusions*. Don't get to the slippery slope that gets you to draw conclusions from any answer you might get because we really still don't know. I'm saying this because usually such questions fall within the theological framework to make gap to put god in. So be careful, and keep in mind the great saying of Feynman:

*"Not knowing is better than knowing a wrong answer"*.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to answer. I guess I know that there cannot be a satisfying answer to this question. My intention of was more of to get some insight on this question. I'll prefer to be curious.

Comment: Laws of the universe are ink on paper put there by men. How can ink on paper appear without there being a universe?

Comment: @CuriousOne I think you're trivializing the matter and missing the point and initiating the logical fallacy "personal incredulity"... I'm not sure there's a constructive purpose of your comment. Please enlighten me if I'm wrong.

Comment: How am I trivializing the matter? I am simply applying the PROPER definitions of what physical laws are. Do I need to explain the scientific method to you?

Comment: @CuriousOne Well, whether the laws of physics are fundamental or whether it's just ink on paper is something that's not judged by your mere observation and experience. The scientific method is `hypothesize->test->theorize and model`. While it doesn't give a general definition and laws are not said to be general, we cannot say that generalizations are wrong until proven wrong. You claiming they're not general is not scientific because it's your personal opinion that you claim because of your (or basically our) limitations.

Comment: Theories and models are ink on paper. That's all they ever have to be. They are special in the sense that they can be translated to physical machines called experiments and that those machines work in a certain way. "War and Peace" doesn't do that, neither do Plato and Aristotle and that is what makes one piece of paper more useful than another. It's still paper.

Comment: @CuriousOne Dude. It's very obvious you're not listening. Let's agree to disagree! That's much easier ;-)

Comment: I am listening. It's a philosophical debate, not a physical one. The problem is that you can't load science with philosophy without wrecking it. Science is not made for that and it's happy with having produced stacks of paper that allow us to make computers for you, fly to Mars every five years and heal some of the sick. It doesn't have to keep you warm at night in addition with fuzzy talk about some abstract platonic "laws" that have nothing to do with physics textbooks.

Comment: @CuriousOne Good for me I'm not a philospher ;-)

Comment: @thokiro why did you remove the check?

Answer (score 6):

This is a metaphysical/philosophical question, imo.

There is the [platonic ideals school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Forms), in this case read for ideals=mathematics, which postulated that ideals existed and nature fell into their form. I have seen a number of theoretically inclined people who are really of that school. One does not have to think of the beginning of the universe to start thinking that the mathematical format is the mold in which nature settles.

So in this school the answer is that "laws and the subsequent theories existed before the observable universe". It becomes metaphysics because it invites a meta level of:" how did these laws and theories appear out of the vacuum".

As an experimental physicist I am of the school that "nature exists and we experimentally study its behavior and fit the data with mathematical models", so the horizon of our knowledge is limited by our experiments and observations. The answer then is like the other answers: we cannot know because we have no observations for the beginning of the universe, only after the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) time in the [BigBang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang), 380.000 years after the beginning. Before that, we fit models and extrapolate back. For a while we thought that [BICEP2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BICEP_and_Keck_Array) had taken us very near to time 0 with gravitational waves, but it turned out not to be rigorously established.

Comment: I find it hard to understand why many or all are thinking of it as just a metaphysical question only because we are limited in our knowledge and understanding of science. After all, metaphysics of today might be main stream physics of tomorrow, like science fiction of yesterday is realistic science of today(almost). Failure in finding answers won't stop us from asking questions. It will only make us more curious and determinant to find answers.

Comment: A metaphysical question means just that :beyond mainstream physics/no answer within mainstream physics. That is what the meta term means. You are correct that the physics of today is the metaphysics of  last centuries, but in the case of ideals, it is a nesting outside the current physics models.  For all the progress since calculus was introduced by Newton, new theories incorporated the old, or showed the the old were emergent. It is hard  to think how the build up of physics models could end up to preexisting  platonic ideals. Thus metaphysics

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, Physics is not able to awnser this question, because the physical laws we use to describe the Universe are not valid up to the exact event of the Big Bang (the Big Bang is said to be a *singularity* of spacetime).

Physics attempts to describe the Universe at a moment when it already existed, but does not states causes for its existence itself.

Answer (score 2):

Semantics is wrong in more than one way. First of all, there is no "first" without time, and time only exists in the universe, so the question is not well posed. If there was something before the big bang, then both are a part of the same "universe/multiverse" for which common laws must hold (you can't just discretely switch laws all of the sudden - and if you do, the way you switch it follows some rules as well, so you can again put it in a bigger unyfing theory). If the big bang really is the edge of the universe (edge in space-time), then you must still look at it as a whole (time+space), so you just have an object (=universe) that just is. Evolution in time is simply a way of slicing it up and experiencing it, and there's where the notion of "first" and sequence of events comes in.

Secondly... you should understand laws as things that *describe* the universe, not the thing that governs it. Telling the rules is similar to saying "this apple is delicious". I guess you could ask "what came first: apples or its taste"... in the sense that the concept of taste somehow transcends the existence of an apple, you may argue that the taste can exist even in a world without apples. Two points must be raised here. Firstly, we argue that taste exists because there are other fruits, there's a bigger universe in which an apple exists. This brings us back to the question of just finding the laws that encapsulate the thing bigger than the universe - which begs the question, if we *define* the universe as everything there is, does it make sense to even talk about "outside the universe"? I'd say no. The second argument is the core of this issue, and probably an answer: the rules of math and logic transcend any reality at all. They are *completely* abstract concepts that are true in any universe you imagine, or without any universe. Truth is absolute - so in that sense... math comes "before" (not in the sense of physical time, but in the process of philosophical reasoning) everything else. Then, the laws that describe your universe are simply truths (facts) about it.

Comment: So, Math>Truth>Reality is it then?

Comment: I'd say Math=Truth, but interpretation can vary. Math is a set of all statements you can make without running into a contradiction. This is why it doens't need a universe to work: it only depends on itself. All statements/definitions/rules have to be consistent with eachother. There is no universe where {1=2, where 1,2 are natural numbers, where natural numbers are defined as [Peano axioms]} is true. Notice how every statement has a "scope" (description what you mean).

Comment: Sorry, this is the old fallacy of mathematicians again. Truth is not absolute. Truth and math are *defined*. They are artifacs of the rules of logic/math and hence our brain. Even if  you go to its maximum depth, you end up at Gödel’s incompleteness theorem. Showing that by itself, it has no basis.
Hence Mathematics (and truth) cannot ever transcend reality, and are mere phantasms and tool of our minds.
Outside of the parts where it makes predictions, and those are verified by perceptions of reality, it is pure religion and pseudoscience. Just like philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

Closely related to your question is that of whether [mathematics is discovered or invented](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/derek-abbott/is-mathematics-invented-o_b_3895622.html). If it is discovered, where does it "live"?

Also relevant might be the view of Tegmark on the [Mathematical Universe Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis) Where he posits that everything is "made of mathematics" and that the physical world is just one such instantiation out of a possible infinite set.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/113758)

Comment: @ACuriousMind It DOES provide an answer if you believe Tegmark is correct

Comment: If I believed Tegmark was correct, this would still be a link-only answer, since you don't actually tell us here what the view of Tegmark *is*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Corrected

Comment: **Neither.** Mathematics is based on logic, which is based on the way our brains (neural nets) work. 1+1=2 because that’s how we *defined* it. Based on pattern and concepts we use. Which is why the deeper you go, the closer to come to pure logic and how neural nets work. Category theory is a great example. Don’t get me wrong: Math is a great tool. But acting like it “is”, outside of our ways of thinking, is veering off into the territory of religion and nonsensical pseudoscience. It is how it is because we are how we are. And that is *fine*. Also, Gödel’s incompleteness theorem kills this.

Answer (score 0):

The "laws" we have found allow to predict how the "universe" manifests itself (including a concrete concept of universe) are nowhere to be found other than our social interactions as agents.

They are in no way in the same phenomenological level than, well, actual observable phenomena (what you call the universe). You can see this hierarchy in the fact that many "laws" can "fit" a single observation.

From a time arrow perspective, they came afterwards, because they appeared after formal-language-augmented social interacting mass-based agents (us) appeared.

Comment: Well, you're just equating "law" with "model" here - we have many different models that ... model ... reality. But what about the *actual* physical laws, the fundamental reality we are trying to model? Maybe your answer is exactly what thokiro is looking for, but to me, it sounds like the good old "If a tree falls and noöne hears it" kind of "philosophical" misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, my answer has that perspective (<> than misunderstanding). Other answers have mentioned this approach: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/derek-abbott/is-mathematics-invented-o_b_3895622.html has been cited, especially points 2 and 3. From other answer: "nature exists and we experimentally study its behavior and fit the data with mathematical models", so the horizon of our knowledge is limited by our experiments and observations.", and "... you should understand laws as things that describe the universe, not the thing that governs it." ... in this view, there are no "actual" laws.